# Print out MongoDB collection documents using Angular

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

I'm making basic login system from NodeJS, Angular and MongoDB.

I want my system will show information about the user (Username and Age) after register or login successfully. But I got a problem.

When I register successful, only show user's age not show username and instead, when I login, it only show username not show age.

I will show some code, where I think got problem:

**Server.js**

```
 // create new user object
var user = new User();
user.username = req.body.user.username;
user.age = req.body.user.age;
user.password = req.body.user.password;
```

**user.js**

```
 //grab the packages that we need for the user model
var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

//user schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required:true, index: {unique:true}},
    age: {type: String, required:true, index: {unique:true}},
    faceId: {type: String, required:false},
    password: {type: String, required:true, select: false},
});


//hash the password before the user is saved
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var user = this;

    //hash the password only if the password has been changed or user is new
    if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    //generate the salt
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
        if (err) return next(err);

        //change the password to the hashed version
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

//method to compare a given password with the database hash
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {
    var user = this;
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
};

//return the model
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**register component**

```
// post user data and image url
this.userRestService.register({
    user: this.user,
    image: this.imageUrl
  }).subscribe(data => {
      var token = data.token;
      this.auth.setToken(token);
      this.auth.setUser({ username: this.user.username });
      this.auth.setUser({ age: this.user.age });
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

**I print out by:**

```
<div *ngIf="user">
<p>
  {{greeting}} {{user.room}} {{user.age}}      
</p>
</div>
```

**Login component :**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, Inject, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { UserRestService } from '../../services/user-rest.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  imageUrl;
  username;
  age;
  password;
  loginMethod: string = 'camera';

  constructor(private router: Router, private userRestService: UserRestService, private auth: AuthService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  // login method
  login() {
    // set params: password or imageUrl, depending on chosen loginMethod
    var params: any = {
      username: this.username
    };
    if(this.loginMethod === 'password') {
      params.password = this.password;
    }
    else {
      params.image = this.imageUrl;
    }

    // perform http call
    this.userRestService.login( {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password,
      image: this.imageUrl
    })
      .subscribe( data => {
          // on success set token and user data
          var token = data.token;
          this.auth.setToken(token);
          this.auth.setUser({username: this.username, age: this.age});
          //this.auth.setUser({room: this.room});


          // navigate to home page
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        });
  }

  // image changed handler for embedded components (image picker, camera snapshot)
  imageChanged(data) {
    this.imageUrl = data;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part:

```
this.auth.setUser({username: this.user.username});
this.auth.setUser({age: this.user.age});
```

You are setting the user twice: once with only the username and once with only the age.

You probably have to set the user object one time only, with the correct object as argument to `setUser()`:

```
this.auth.setUser({username: this.user.username, age: this.user.age});
```

You probably have the same error for the login part.

Comment: thanks for your support. I fixed.It show username name age.  
But when I login, it only show username not show age.
I added login component above.

Comment: The reason you don't get the age after logging in is because your login endpoint doesn't send user information to Angular. You send the token, which you read with `var token = data.token`, but there is no way for Angular to know the age. The username is read from the login input box. You should try to return the user object (line 141 AND 171 in the pastebin) and then use the returned user object together with setUser. See [this](https://pastebin.com/hzMgbHhg) pastebin. I wrote line 171 there. Should be 141 too.

Comment: I would like to say thank you for all of your enthusiasm. Maybe I got another bug. I will rely on your suggestions to fix it. Thanks you very much.